# Parsing a text file in android from an HTML

Tags: java, android, html, parsing

So I have been working on this for a bit and hit a brick wall. It keeps giving me a fatal error when it start to process.
So basically I want to read in a text file off the internet and then parse it so I can start to break that apart and use a JSON parser to deal with JSON data. But that further down the line (and i have the part built). I just am having trouble with the connection and downloading of the data. I just want to read in the text file and then print it out again.
Thank you for any help with this.

This is what it gives me

> 01-26 15:11:48.373 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>       01-26 15:11:48.556 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser D/HTML P1:: http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt
>       01-26 15:11:48.556 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser D/HTML P2:: http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt
>       01-26 15:11:48.557 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser D/HTML inJSON:: http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt
>       01-26 15:11:48.569 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser D/Status:: Connection Opened
>       01-26 15:11:48.569 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser D/Status::  Closing connection
>       01-26 15:11:48.569 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       01-26 15:11:48.570 1958-1958/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser, PID: 1958
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser/com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                         Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>                                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>                                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
>                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
>                                                                                            at com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser.JSONParser.getStream(JSONParser.java:40)
>                                                                                            at com.example.mmillar.urljsonparser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>       01-26 15:11:53.474 1958-1958/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1958 SIG: 9

So I'm a bit lost to where this is going wrong. I think I have everything set up and going good. Like the inputstream, bufferreader and all. So here is what I have.

This is the Parser program

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... inputUrl) {
    getStream(inputUrl[0]);
    return null;
}

public void getStream(String urlString)
{
    Log.d("HTML inJSON: ", urlString );
    //variables for the connection and downloading the JSON data
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        Log.d("Status:","Connection Opened");
        //read in the data
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        //build the data for parsing
        StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            myString.append(line);
        }
        Log.d("Status:"," JSON loaded into string");
        Log.d("Total:", myString.toString());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
        {
            //close the connection
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.d("Status:", " Closing connection");
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is the main program I just run the thing because I just want to output from the file to the console I just want to make sure it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt
private String testHtml = "http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("HTML P1: ", testHtml );
    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
    Log.d("HTML P2: ", testHtml );
    jp.getStream(testHtml);
    Log.d("HTML P3: ", testHtml);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using

```
jp.getStream(testHtml);
```

use

```
jp.execute("stream url here");
```

Currently you are trying to create a function in your `Asynctask`, but are not leveraging the use of `AsyncTask`. It still tries to make a HttpConnection on the mainThread, and that throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks that worked, Ok just so I get why, I think that the main thread cannot make the connection because it doesnt have all the URL links and stuff in it. Or is it because there is one that is open already and then it is just closing that one and giving a error? Thank you once again

Comment: Glad that i could be of any help. :)

The issue arises because by default, the Android ThreadPolicy blocks any network usage on UI thread. It can be bypassed using the following 

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

but this is not generally advised to call any network operation on UI thread.